# How to get purchased product in iOS In App Purchase?

Tags: ios, ios8, in-app-purchase, xcode6, nsuserdefaults

I am very new to In App Purchase. My app is having 50 Audiobooks. Which can be purchased through In App Purchase. I have two questions

1. If user is purchasing one book from shop. I can add it to library but if user quits the app and open again how could I know the last purchased product? Is it ok to use NSUserdefault to store the purchased book ID? (Note: My app don't have user registration)
2. I have restore option in my app, On restore I am getting all the previously purchased product id (I have created the IN-App purchase ID as book ID). I am getting that ID send the ID to backend and getting the book details and showing it in app is it the right way?

   My app got rejected twice this is the third time, So also kindly share some of the reasons apple rejects In-App purchase if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: which reason provide apple for your app reject

Comment: We found that your app offers In-App Purchase(s) that can be restored but does not include a “Restore Purchases" feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased In-App Purchase(s), as specified in the “Restoring Purchase Products” section of the In-App Purchase Programming Guide
Please note that although guideline 11.6 of the App Store Review Guidelines requires an application to make subscription content available to all the iOS devices owned by a single user, it is not appropriate to force user registration to meet this requirement; such user registration must be made optional.